# iframe content fill when content not loaded Facebook specific

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I am installing a Facebook-like box in iframe form. When you are not logged into Facebook, it leaves a blank spot that is set to the parameters specified by the original iframe. I would like to fill that iframe with an image to link to the Facebook page when someone is not logged into Facebook.

Logged In:
http://ripvision.tv/images/fb-logged-in.PNG

Not Logged In:
http://ripvision.tv/images/fb-not-logged-in.PNG

You can see on the "Logged In" that I was trying to set a class with a background image to show up when the content didn't show up but that showed up when content loaded and without. I would just like it to load an image link if the Facebook content doesn't load. I have tried everything I can think of.

I thought adding a background-color into the style of the iframe would work but it didn't. Here is the iframe code from Facebook.

```
   <iframe class="fb_background" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http  %3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fteamripoutdoors&amp;width=236&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:258px; background-color: #000;"  allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I have been stumped on this for hours. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `FB.getLoginStatus` to this

> `FB.getLoginStatus` allows you to determine if a user is logged in to
>   Facebook and has authenticated your app. There are three possible
>   states for a user:
>
> 1. the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your
>      application (connected)
> 2. the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application 
>      (not_authorized)
> 3. the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)

In this case we will use 
`not_authorized` which means the user is logged into their Facebook account and will show the like box

`unknown` means the user is not logged into their Facebook account and show a fallback image

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

  if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
    $('#likeBoxDiv').fadeIn();
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    $('#likeBoxDiv').html('{YOUR_FALLBACK_DIV');
  }

});
```

Here's a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/VasPn/)

Remember: create an App for this and **don't authenticate any user with this app** otherwise you have to add `connected` statement, too